# Injecting Map<String,Object> into Constructor based on Type of Class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have multiple classes that all that need a `Map<String,Object>` injected into their constructors to supply default configurations that will be overridden by the user if needed.

```
@Inject
MyClass(@Nonnull final Map<String,Object> defaults) {}
```

There are lots of these all different types but they all have the same constructor signature. I know about `@Named()` but I a do not want to have to manage a bunch of configuration of `String` keys if there is a better way to inject a something based on the receiver class type.

I need something like but I can't find anything that looks like it does this.

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String,Object>>(){}).where(MyClass.class).toInstance(ImmutableMap.<String,Object>of());
```

#### How do I configure a binding to bind an instance to a constructor based on the Type of the receiving class the constructor belongs to?

Comment: I wrote a library called `sangria-contextual` that can do this: [blog post](https://tavianator.com/announcing-sangria/), [GitHub](https://github.com/tavianator/sangria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

There does not seem to be a way to do this without manually adding some kind of metadata for Guice to trigger on. I wanted something with less overhead maintenance wise, but this is better than `@Named` since it is constants that can be compile time checked at least.

#### Custom Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import com.google.inject.BindingAnnotation;

@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Defaults { public Class value(); }
```

#### Module that binds the annotated parameters to instances:

```
public class DefaultsModule extends AbstractModule
{

        private static class Defaults implements com.mycompany.guice.Defaults, Serializable
    {
        private final Class value;

        private Defaults() { this.value = null; }

        Defaults(@Nonnull final Class value) { this.value = checkNotNull(value); }

        public Class value() { return this.value; }

        public int hashCode() { /* This is specified in java.lang.Annotation. */ return (127 * "value".hashCode()) ^ value.hashCode(); }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() { return com.mycompany.guice.Defaults.class; }

        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if (!(o instanceof Defaults)) { return false; }
            com.mycompany.guice.Defaults other = (com.mycompany.guice.Defaults) o;
            return value.equals(other.value());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, Object>>() {}).annotatedWith(new Defaults(MyClassThatNeedsDefaults.class)).toInstance(/* omitted for brevity */);
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

And then you use it just like `@Named`, but it is not relying on a `String`!

```
@Inject
MyClassThatNeedsDefaults(@Nonnull @Defaults(MyClassThatNeedsDefaults.class) final Map<String,Object> defaults) { this.defaults = defaults; }
```